# How to program puppet to extract tarball only if its different

Tags: puppet

I want to use puppet to do this :

1. First puppet run, extract contents of tarball (which is stored on some server)
2. Subsequent puppet runs, extract contents of the tarball only if the tarball is different from the earlier run

Any suggestions on how to do this in Puppet ? I am struggling with how to use the "onlyif" clause in Puppet to achieve this.

Comment: With or without use of the `archive` module?

Comment: Ideally without

Comment: Are you delivering this tarball from the master or is it already there?

Comment: Its already there, I don't need the master to push it

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in just one puppet run with something like:

```
$filename = 'somefile'
$path = '/somepath'

file { 'filename':
 ensure => file,
 source => 'file:/<SOMEPATH>/<SOMEFILE>',
 path   => "${path}/${filename}",
 notify => Exec['extract tar'],
}

exec { 'extract tar':
 refreshonly => true,
 command     => "tar --overwrite -xf ${filename}",
 path        => '/bin',
 cwd         => $path,
}
```

But I think using puppet/archive module would be a cleaner solution.

Comment: Wont this run every single time, regardless whether the tar is updated or not ?

Comment: No. When refreshonly is set to true, the exec will only run if it gets a notification from another resource. And the file resource will only send an notify if it makes changes to the system ie when the file is changed.